# Downloaded the Ubuntu ISO from torrent and normal download, but they're not the same size

Tags: downloads, iso

There two version of Ubuntu 12.10 the normal download in browser and the the one from torrent and and the torrent download file size in total is (800 MB) and and normal download is (763 MB) which should I get because I know you are updating the ISO sometimes so which one is the updated one?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

I think the torrent you downloaded is a 64-bit version of ubuntu, is this correct? Try downloading from the Ubuntu website, and download according to your architecture (if you are not sure, just download the 32-bit version).

Comment: both of them are 64 bit and they have 38 MB differences and they are 12.10

Comment: Okay, then I recommend downloading the one from the website (the torrent could be broken). It always worked for me :)

Comment: ok thx for help

Comment: glad I was able to help :D

Comment: You should try the checksum for both of them. Although unlikely, the torrent could be alright and the one from the website broken.

Comment: @Bolt64, but why would the torrent be 800MB though? Ubuntu said that 12.10 would be 750MB